# Creating FTP Site on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, ftp, web

I got approximately 20 web sites hosted in my IIS. Until now, I was creating ftp sites assigning them into different ftp ports for each. So that, I didn't need to type my username as in the syntax like 'hostname|username'. However, It's getting hard to remember all the ports of each ftp sites. Therefore, I need to find a way for creating ftp sites that are using port 21 and also I want to not to type 'hostname|' in order to determine which ftp i'm logging into. How can I solve this problem? I got IIS 7.5 installed on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guide](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/305/configuring-ftp-75-user-isolation/) from iis.net says it better than I could!

You should be able to set up a new FTP site on a single port that routes a username to their personal folder - all on one port!